# Filtering table columns using checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a table where I am trying to filter the columns that are shown based on whether a checkbox is checked or not. I have it working mostly except for the first column which doesn't act as expected (i.e. more is hidden than just the column). I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n208wxbo/2/) which exhibits this behaviour. As you can see, the second column is toggled as expected, but the first also removes other elements which I don't want to happen. I am not sure what is occurring as in my mind this should work. Can anyone point out where the mistake in my code is, and help me to fix it?

I am currently using this to filter (as can be seen in the fiddle):

```
$('#columnCheckboxes input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    let colToHide = $('#matrixTable th').filter("." + $(this).attr("name"));
    let index = $(colToHide).index();
    $('#matrixTable').find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').toggle();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the html I am using:

```
<div>
    <div class="dropdown mb-2">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="columnFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-th fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="columnFilter" id="columnCheckboxes">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="1" checked />&nbsp;Delivery Orders</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="2" checked />&nbsp;Walk-in Orders</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="matrixTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th colspan="2">Event</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Activity</th>
                <th class="1">Delivery Orders</th>
                <th class="2">Walk-in Orders</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    Till Activity
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    Delivery Activity
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    Pick Activity
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the checkboxes in your fiddle, but the console says, _“Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)”_ - please go fix that. Also include the minimum of HTML necessary to reproduce the problem directly inside your question as well.

Comment: @CBroe I updated with html and the fiddle should be working now

Comment: You are selecting too many elements with `tr :nth-child(...` - other elements _inside_ the table cells are also the n-th child of their respective parents. Make that `tr > :nth-child(...` instead, to only select the first child of the table _rows_ here.

Comment: And FYI, nesting an interactive element such as input into `a` is not allowed, that’s invalid HTML. You should remove the links around the checkboxes, and _add_ a label, so that the text becomes clickable as well, and user don’t have to target the tiny checkbox exactly.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it still results in the same. Here is an updated fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/n208wxbo/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/n208wxbo/5/)

Comment: Your table header has a different number of columns than the table body, so you should either limit this to the table rows inside the tbody (https://jsfiddle.net/n208wxbo/6/) - or you will have to first of all _specify_ what you actually want to happen to `<th colspan="2">Event</th>` when either one of the _two_ columns below it gets hidden.

Comment: Try this and see if it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/n208wxbo/3/

Comment: @kastriotcunaku That works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "Event" cell belongs to the second column which is the column of "Delivery Orders". That's why it hides when you clicked to hide the "Delivery Orders" column. You may add HTML classes to help jQuery identify what it needs to hide or display.